# Data Visualization apps: WP8 and Windows store

Tags: windows, windows-phone-8, windows-store-apps

How do i make data visualization application in windows store and windowsphone8 app without using paid features like telerik. Also suggest paid ones if any.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows Store App, You can use [Windows 8 Toolkit - Charts and More](http://modernuitoolkit.codeplex.com/) in CodePlex. There are Pie chart/ Line chart/Column chart and so on.

In Windows Phone App, You can use `the same solution with Silverlight`. Read [This sample](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/delay/archive/2010/04/20/phone-y-charts-silverlight-wpf-data-visualization-development-release-4-and-windows-phone-7-charting-sample.aspx) please.Here is [Silverlight Toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/) in CodePlex.